# Get chart name with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am setting up a macro to generate a chart. I have recorded a macro while I was generating the sample chart, but now I need to have the macro working independently from the name of the chart (`Chart 9` in this case)

```
Sheets("statistics").Select
Sheets("statistics").Range("A101:C106").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("statistics!$A$101:$C$106")
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 9").Name = "waterfall"
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="summary"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("waterfall").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("waterfall").IncrementLeft 80
ActiveSheet.Shapes("waterfall").IncrementTop -2200
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("waterfall").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("waterfall").ScaleWidth 1.6025463692, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("waterfall").ScaleHeight 1.6084106153, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("waterfall").Activate
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("waterfall").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(6).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Solid
End With
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Solid
End With
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(5).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
    .Solid
End With
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleHorizontal)
Selection.Caption = "hrs"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Left = 7
Selection.Top = 13.028
```

I have tried

```
Sheets("statistics").Range("A101:C106").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("statistics!$A$101:$C$106")
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
Set ThisChart = ActiveChart
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ThisChart).Name = "waterfall"
```

but it is not working

Comment: Are you creating just 1 chart per sheet or multiple charts?

Comment: it's up to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below, it will loop through all existing `ChartObjects` in "statistics" worksheet, and if it finds a chartobject with a name of "Chart 9" it will rename it to "waterfall".

**Note**: you could use a similar approach to create the chart, without the need to use `Select`, `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveChart`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameExistingChart()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

For Each ChtObj In Worksheets("statistics").ChartObjects
    If ChtObj.Name = "Chart 9" Then
        ChtObj.Name = "waterfall"
    End If
Next ChtObj

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: create the chart with `ChtObj`:

```
Set ChtObj = Worksheets("statistics").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, _
                                    Width:=100, Height:=100) ' <-- just default settings , modify later    
With ChtObj
    .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=range("statistics!$A$101:$C$106")
    .Name = "waterfall"

    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill ' modify fill for series (2)
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent3
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels ' add data lables to series (1)

End With
```

Comment: maybe my question was not clear. I am editing it for the purpose.

Comment: @L.Dutch what are you trying to do ? I guess I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want the macro to work on the chart it creates, independently from its name

Comment: yes, now it creates the chart, but then it messes up the rest of the recorded macro, where all the ActiveChart fail

Comment: @L.Dutch why do you want to use `ActiveChart` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136354/discussion-between-l-dutch-and-shai-rado).

Comment: @L.Dutch see edited code under **Edit 1** to modify more of the chart's settings, like series and datalabels

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
Sub ChartStuff()
Dim cht As Shape
Range("A101:A106").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
cht.Name = "waterfall"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if there is more than one chart per sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with charts in VBA is a little complicated.
When you use `Addchart`, Selection will be a `ChartArea`
A `ChartArea` is part of a Chart which is part of a `ChartObject`
The name of a chart you see is in fact the name of the `ChartObject`

You can do something like this:

```
Range("A101:A106").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

Dim ca As ChartArea, ch As Chart, co As ChartObject
Set ca = Selection 
Set ch = ca.Parent
ch.ChartType = xl3DColumn
Set co = ch.Parent
co.Name = "waterfall"
Debug.Print ca.Name, ch.Name, co.Name
```

Comment: It's actually very easy to get a reference to the chart directly: `Set ch = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart`

Comment: You're right. It's confusing that the return value is a `Chart` while the Selection is a `ChartArea`...

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that you call from within the sub, that sends the name of the active chart, for example:

```
Function actchart(ActiveChart As String) As String
  actchart = ActiveChart
End Function
```

And then from within your sub, you can replace, as an example, where you have:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 9").Name = "waterfall"
```

with

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(actchart(ActiveChart.Parent.Name)).Name = "waterfall"
```

This worked for me with the same issue! Hope it helps.